# Using Bootstrap theme and anonymous user, ajax form submit results in "call to undefined function bootstrap_form_process"

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, theming

**Context**

We have a subtheme based on the Bootstrap theme and we're rendering a form inside of a modal. The submit button uses an ajax callback to handle form submission.

**Problem**

When logged in as an admin in Chrome, the form submits perfectly.

When logged out (accessing the site as an anonymous user) in Chrome, submitting the form results in a 500 Server error.

The server logs are reporting "Call to undefined function bootstrap_form_process()".

**Research**

It seems that this might be related (https://www.drupal.org/node/2156371) but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

I have a hard time following issue discussions on drupal.org. I have a decent amount of Drupal knowledge, but still struggle to figure out what they are saying.

**Things I've Tried**

Some people in the thread linked above got around the issue by setting max_input_vars to 2000, so I gave that a shot. It didn't help.

I thought maybe I needed to increase it even more, so I set it to 5000, but still no change. I then switched it back to the default 1000.

I also tried adding "drupal_static_reset('element_info');" to my theme's template.php file, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to https://www.drupal.org/node/2369635, i.e. you need to include `/path/to/bootstrap/includes/process.inc` in your codebase.  The easiest way IMHO is in a `hook_init()` somewhere.